# Python cross compilation to Windows with Nuitka failing

Tags: python, compilation, cross-compiling, wine, nuitka

I'm trying to compile a Python 3 file into a Windows executable from inside Ubuntu using Nuitka with the instructions [here](http://nuitka.net/doc/user-manual.html#use-case-4-cross-compilation-to-windows). When trying to compile, I get the error

```
Error, no 'Python.h' development headers can be found, dependency not satisfied!
```

It works when I try to compile for Linux, though

I have the `python3-dev` package installed and have Python 3 installed in Wine. What can I do to install the Python development headers in Wine?

EDIT: It seems that the header files exist at `/home/$USER/.wine/drive_c/Python33/include` but Nuitka doesn't see them?

Comment: I ended up using a Windows VM with MinGW to compile my Windows files but any other solutions would by welcomed.

Comment: what about running nuitka from within the wine instance?